# gtk-builder-error-quark: invalid object type 'WebKitWebView'

Tags: python, gtk, webkit, gtk3

I am getting the following error when trying to get a `WebKitWebView` object via `Gtk.builder()`:

```
$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    builder.add_from_file("ui.glade")
gi.repository.GLib.Error: gtk-builder-error-quark: ui.glade:31:1 Invalid object type 'WebKitWebView' (6)
```

Here's my Python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gi
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import WebKit2 as Webkit

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("ui.glade")

window = builder.get_object("window")
window.set_title("Test")

webview = builder.get_object("webview")

if __name__ == "__main__": 
  window.show_all()
  Gtk.main()
```

And here's my `ui.glade` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <requires lib="webkit2gtk" version="2.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="width_request">800</property>
    <property name="height_request">600</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="WebKitWebView" id="webview">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010820/glade-invalid-object-type-webkitwebview-when-loading-from-file-works-on-gla), but I honestly didn't "get the point" as the answer said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

There is a bug that gtk_builder_get_type_from_name doesn't work with WebKitWebView.

> The problem is it is looking for the symbol web_kit_web_view_get_type, when it needs to look for webkit_web_view_get_type. This is unfortunate. I'm not sure what to do about this.
>
> Workaround: manually register the type before creating the GtkBuilder. Something like g_object_unref (g_object_ref_sink (webkit_web_view_new ())) should work.

see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=175937

There are multiple workarounds possible.

**Workaround 1**

One solution could be to create the web view in code

```
webview = Webkit.WebView()
```

In the ui.glade file, replace WebKitWebView with GtkScrolledWindow, perhaps an id like 'scrolled_window' would be more appropriate. The `expand` property should then be set to `True'.

After reading the glade file, you can do the following:

```
scrolled_window = builder.get_object("scrolled")
scrolled_window.add_with_viewport(webview)

webview.load_uri("https://www.google.com")
```

**Workaround 2**

Alternatively, you could just call (the call itself is sufficient, you don't have to assign it to a variable), before calling Gtk.Builder():

```
Webkit.WebView()
```

This is equivalent to the above mentioned
workaround from the linked bug report with a call of webkit_web_view_new().

However, the `expand` property should still be set to `True` for WebKitWebView in the ui.glade file.

**Demo**

On Ubuntu, it would look like this in both cases:

[image: Demo Webkit.WebView]

Comment: What's the point here, you can place `WebKitWebView` in `Glade` but `Builder` can't instaniate it?

Comment: While this is a nice workaround, it doesn't answer the gtk builder error message and why it's happening.

Comment: Due to a bug, a workaround is required. I have added details and a link to the bug report and an alternative workaround if you prefer to leave the WebKitWebView definition in the .glade file.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht: Thanks for explanation. I'm interested in ***"Workaround: manually register..."***, can you point to a Python reference.

Comment: Basically, calling Webkit.WebView() in Python before creating the Gtk.Builder is the equivalent of calling webkit_web_view_new() mentioned in the above quote, see workaround 2 of my answer. By the way: the linked bug report further down even mention another possibility, simply calling webkit_web_view_get_type(). So there are many possible workarounds ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> **Question**: gtk-builder-error-quark: invalid object type 'WebKitWebView'

It seems to be a `scope and namespace` issue which `Gtk.Builder` can't resolve.

Found this simple solution to bring the requiered classes `WebKit2.WebView` and `WebKit2.Settings` into the module `namespace`.

> Note: **You don't have to change anything within `Glade`, place `WebKit2` objects as usual**.

Change the `import` from

```
from gi.repository import WebKit2 as Webkit
```

to

```
from gi.repository.WebKit2 import WebView, Settings
```

---

If you **don't want** to define the used classes **one by one**, consider this **on request** solution.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import WebKit2 as Webkit


class GtkBuilder(Gtk.Builder):
    def do_get_type_from_name(self, type_name):
        """
        Looks up a type by name, using the virtual function that Gtk.Builder 
        has for that purpose.

        Parameters:  type_name (str) – type name to lookup
        Returns:     the GObject.GType found for type_name 
                       or GObject.TYPE_INVALID if no type was found
        Return type: GObject.GType

        """

        if type_name.startswith('WebKit'):
            getattr(Webkit, type_name[6:])

        r = Gtk.Builder.do_get_type_from_name(self, type_name)
        print('GtkBuilder: => {}\t{}'.format(type_name, r))
        return r
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> GtkBuilder: => WebKitSettings   <GType WebKitSettings (4168054944)>
> GtkBuilder: => GtkWindow    <GType GtkWindow (4167639152)>
> GtkBuilder: => GtkBox   <GType GtkBox (4167624432)>
> GtkBuilder: => GtkEntry <GType GtkEntry (4168904384)>
> GtkBuilder: => WebKitWebView    <GType WebKitWebView (4168054192)>
> ```

---

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - gi.__version__: 3.22.0 - Glade 3.22.1***

Comment: The less intrusive solution is for sure manually importing the classes. Kudos!